# Distorted Newton binomial

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $\varepsilon >0$, with $\varepsilon \neq 1$. Consider the sequence $u_n$ defined by

$$
u_n=\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k}^2 (-\varepsilon)^k
$$

Is is true that $(u_n)$ takes on negative and positive values infinitely
often, while $|u_n| \to +\infty$ when $n\to \infty$ ?

Perhaps this problem is very hard. If so, any assessments about the difficulty are welcome.